# Is "remove commented out code" correct English?

Tags: expressions

As a programmer, I often use the term "Remove commented out code" as a commit message when checking in code. I wonder whether this is correct English.

To use an example outside the realm of programming, consider these two phrases for contrast:

"Help the poor people"

"Help the left behind people"

The first seems reasonable, while the second sounds clunky. Is it grammatically correct? I assume it could be said better.

What about my initial example? Is there a better way to phrase it or is it ok?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92043/discussion-on-question-by-cerno-is-remove-commented-out-code-correct-english).

Comment: In a commit message, you are defining the actions you took in that commit. Defining an action that has been completed, is done using the **past tense**. So "Remove" should be "Removed".

Comment: A simple hyphen would make "commented-out" a compound adjective - and then it's fine.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a better way to phrase it, but it's also OK.  That is to say, in contexts other than a commit message, you would probably want to rewrite the sentence, but for an internal note, it's fine.

The main issue with the sentence is that you're using *commented out* as a compound adjective and so you should probably hyphenate the phrase: "Remove the commented-out code." Hyphenation would also improve your last example sentence: "Help the left-behind people" is better, but "Help the people who were left behind" is better still.

If I were trying to express the idea of your commit message in a more formal context, a context where prose style is important, or really any context without a strict and low character limit, I would write, "Remove the code which was commented out."

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for, both from the perspective of a commit message and a more embellished version, thanks!

Comment: Your answer is grammatically correct, but it misses an important fact: "commented-out code" is *idiomatic* in the relevant domain of expertise. The phrase is widely used and well understood by programmers. I would not have a problem using it even in a formal context. Because "commented-out code" is idiomatic, "code which was commented out" is unnecessarily wordy and may intone smugness.

Comment: @jpmc26, "user login" is also a common idiom; do you find "users who are logged in" to be too wordy? I don't see how the common use of the description "commented-out" precludes the use of the phrasal verb. How would you describe the process of producing commented-out code? "I made it commented-out" or "I commented-outed the code"? It seems to me (and I too am professionally familiar with the term) like the most natural expression would be "I commented out the code." Thus a natural rephrasing would be "It was commented out (by me)."

Comment: @Juhasz "User login" is a synonym for "account," not a user in the logged in state. The idiomatic short phrase for "users who are logged in" would be "authenticated users." "Logged-in users" would be recognizable but not idiomatic. More relevant to this question, "users who are authenticated" would certainly sound strange in most contexts. I'm not sure what the rest has to do with reformulating the phrase into "the code which was commented out."

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but for programming specifically, I'll agree and say "Remove the commented-out code" is better for a commit message.  If the commit message was "Remove the code which was commented out" it leads me to sit and think, did mean that you removed code (for all practical purposes) by commenting it out? Or was there code, commented out, and was removed?

Comment: @jpmc26 Ack, be careful about universalizing your own dialect. Your *criticisms* are all correct, but "user login" is an *event* (a "user account" is just that), "logged-in users" is perfectly idiomatic (authentication can be performed in other ways, such as with OAuth), and using an adjective like "authenticated" in an adjective clause has more to do with the train of thought of the speaker than style.

Comment: Commit messages and idiomatic jargon are pretty far away from formal writing, there's no conflict here. Use "commented-out code" in your commits, tweets, and emails, use more formal language in your presentation to the Queen of Sweden.

Comment: Is that the problem? How about the use of "remove" instead of "removed"? Is "removed" incorrect in that sentence?

Comment: @user4052054 It is recommended to use an imperative verb as the first word of a commit message. Or you can think of it as completing this sentence: "Applying this commit will ...". With version control you can check out a past version of the code with many (future) commits ahead of it. The past tense for commits further ahead then doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would not insert the word "the" into the message. It implies that _all_ the commented out code is removed in that commit, which is unlikely for most projects, unless it refers just to the commented out code that was introduced as part of the current change. You could say "Remove some commented out code", but "some" is not strictly necessary.

Comment: +1 for suggesting hyphenation.  This is one of many cases where using hyphenation would make text clearer and less ambiguous.  Many people seem afraid of hyphens, but they definitely have their place!

Comment: I also like the hyphenation with this specific example because my left behind and right behind are quite different from those who have a logical or physical distal relationship reference interference.

Comment: @CJDennis Interesting. I always thought that the commits should be read as "I..." + message.

Comment: Agree on hyphenation. When phrasal verbs are used  as a part of speech other than verb, they should be hyphenated or a single word (examples of single words derived from phrasal verbs: "pickup", "roundup", "leftovers").

Comment: Isn't there an error in this answer? "Remove the code THAT was commented out."?

Comment: @jpmc26 Agree with everything you've said *except* in my experience "logged-in users" is not only perfectly idiomatic, but more common than authenticated users, which is also common, but savors of formality.  I think you can make a case that "authenticated users" is better and *should be* more common, but in actual usage, especially spoken, it's just not so.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie No, that is not an error. _Which_ is not limited to restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: And then some of us cringe at using `which` instead of `that`, because even though we know `which` can be restrictive, it isn't always. So let's prefer `that` when we do want restriction.

Answer (score 29):

Commit summaries (the single first line of a commit, and often the entire message) are [a defined genre of technical speech](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/) because they have a specific role of identifying changes in a big list of changes and are limited to a certain number of characters. In particular, they are usually written in imperative ("Remove" vs. "Removed") and in [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) for the same goal of fitting information into a limited space. Thus these are all considered helpful commit summaries:

> - Remove commented-out code
> - Refactor foo service
> - Add new SMS implementation for Bar Mobile

As noted elsewhere, "commented-out" should be hyphenated as it's a *phrasal adjective*; otherwise, the way you're phrasing it is stylistically *preferred* for this specific context.

Comment: When I'm writing my commit messages I start by writing a headline, then I go back and make it a grammatically correct regular English sentence. Mostly this consists of adding articles, which function as a sort of "semantic lubricant", aiding fast comprehension. E.g. "Refactor **the** foo service _for reason ..._", "Add **a** new SMS implementation for Bar Mobile", etc.

Comment: @CJDennis It's not really *harmful* to do that, but it's more important to keep to 72 characters than to add lubricant.

Comment: Who says that in the 21st century it's important to not go above 72 characters? My commit messages sometimes have single lines longer than 72 characters, and a total count of thousands of characters without issues.

Comment: @CJDennis It's fine on commit *messages*; I sometimes write multiple paragraphs. The commit *summary*, on the other hand, is processed by tons of tooling, and GitHub, for example, will truncate it.

Comment: From what I've seen, GitHub doesn't truncate it (i.e. only store the first 72 characters), but in certain limited views it will show the first 72 characters as a preview. The full text is visible in a different view. My advice is that if you need more than 72 characters, use them! A 100 character commit summary (without irrelevancies) is unlikely to go under 72 characters by changing it to "headlinese".

Comment: @CJDennis you can use as many characters as you want in a *message* but 72 is the standard for *headings* which is the first line. I don't want to go back and forth between views to know what the summary of the message is - `FEAT1234: Making changes to the authentication procedure to allow for Single Sign-On users` is too long and it will cut of at `allow for S`. OK, I made this a bit too word-y but the idea is that a *descriptive* doesn't really fit. A message of "Change authentication for SSO users" is enough as a heading - write an essay as the message, if you want.

Comment: @Aethenosity The majority of programmers don't work at your workplace. I always question arbitrary length restrictions. Applying length restrictions universally because one day someone might use software that has trouble with it is a bad idea in my opinion. You can't predict all behaviour in advance, especially bugs.

Comment: @Aethenosity Obviously if your workplace says to do it and you don't want to make waves, then do it. However, I was asking why should I and every other programmer do it, since it was presented as general advice. One of my workplaces preferred clarity over short messages, and that is an equally valid view.

Comment: @Aethenosity If I've insulted anyone I apologise. That wasn't my intention, nor to express incredulity (putting words in my mouth?). I was merely questioning the authority behind the claim. I still believe that advice specific to a situation should not be presented as general advice. "It's more important to X than Y" is meant to apply to everyone. "It's more important _where I work_ to X than Y" acknowledges that it's not a universal rule.

Comment: @CJDennis You use UTF-8, right? Why?

Answer (score -8):

Just to add the pedantic view, 'out' is essentially redundant.

'*Remove commented code*' works, or to more accurately explain the commit '*Remove obsolete code*' is probably better.

Having said that, 'commented out' is pretty much an industry term.  If you wish to keep the 'out' (to differentiate from regular language comments that assist future readers, as opposed to comments that hide code from the compiler, I suppose), I see no *need* to hyphenate the term.  It is common enough (especially among your target audience: commit log readers) to be immediately recognised and doesn't create ambiguity when left un-hyphenated.

Comment: _'commented out' is pretty much an industry term_ — Right. And unfortunately for your first paragraph, so is 'commented code'! Commented code (especially _well_ commented code) is a pro, not a con. "Gallant's code is commented. Goofus's code is commented out." (So "Remove commented code" would be less technically correct, but of course a human reader would supply the missing "out" from context.)

Comment: I agree generally, but I'd argue the term you refer to is just 'commented'.  A non-dev looking over my shoulder asked what all the different VS colours were for.  After going through identifiers, key words, strings etc, I said all the dark green stuff was simply commented code (which included both informative stuff and bits I hadn't gotten rid of yet).  Strictly speaking the comments you refer to aren't *code* - as in, if you removed the comment symbols, the compiler would probably throw up syntax errors.  I did mention pedantry, yeah?

Comment: Most people I know would consider "commented code" to refer to code that has comments in it, and "commented-out code" to refer to code that is put between comment markings in order to make the compiler/interpreter ignore it. They are not synonyms in the common usage that I know, so the "out" is not redundant. In fact, "comment out" is a phrasal verb modelled on "cross out", "scratch out", and "rub out", all of which have quite distinct meanings if "out" is omitted.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters. To me "commented-out code" has a very different meaning from "commented code".  The latter meaning code that includes comments, the former being code that has become a comment and is now obsolete. They are *not* synonymous.

Comment: I agree, so this answer is wrong: "commented code" and "commented-out code" are different things. What is more, "obsolete code" is different yet again: it usually won't have been commented out.

Comment: @mcalex "After going through identifiers, key words, strings etc, I said all the dark green stuff was simply commented code ..." this is actually, technically, just wrong, and maybe the source of your confusion re: the responses here. The "green stuff" *itself* is **not** "commented code". It is code comments, commonly referred to within domain as simply "comments". It may **CONTAIN** code that *has been* "commented out" (meaning: rendered into being a comment). Code that has comments ON IT (usually to the right, or above/below) is "commented code"... to be *actually* pedantic.